# Library architecture for helpers and utility functions

Tags: architecture, helper, utilities

How do you handle helpers and utility functions in your project? We have all our classes and helpers in a Core project, but I dont want all this stuff referenced over the other projects when all I want is a helper function. Probably I´ll need to break it down further, but would like som suggestions on the road.

Answer (score 0):

We use a private/internal NuGet server for this. But only for helper functions and/or libraries we use on a lot of projects/components. Via NuGet you can even specify versions, old and/or beta versions, etc. Works very well for us. Just know that when there's a bug in one of the functions, that you have some documentation on what is used where.

Don't forget to read up on the [11th fallacy of distributed computing](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2012/04/26/the-11th-fallacy-of-enterprise-computing.aspx) as well.